# unable to pull python from official docker registry

Tags: python, docker, docker-registry

When I use `docker pull python:3` it outputs:

```
3: Pulling from library/python
32fb02163b6b: Retrying in 1 second
167c7feebee8: Retrying in 1 second
d6dfff1f6f3d: Retrying in 1 second
e9cdcd4942eb: Waiting
ca3bce705f6c: Waiting
5e1c6c4f8bbf: Waiting
2da42ff3382c: Waiting
86f9457966ab: Waiting
896264e2a03c: Waiting
error pulling image configuration: download failed after attempts=6: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

How is that possible if per default it pulls from the official docker registry?

Comment: This usually occurs when there is some kind of proxy intercepting the SSL connections and signing them with their own certificate. E.g. a company proxy or software similar to Charles. Your could try to run `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect docker.io:443` to get some information about the certificate used to sign the SSL connection and the issuer

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, does that mean I have to change my router settings or how can I fix the problem?

Comment: That depends on how exactly your network is setup. The common "fix" is to simply import the certificate (or rather the issuing CA) that is used to sign the connections as trusted into your OS. You would need to find out what intercepts the connection. Depending on how firewalls are setup there might be no way to get a "clean" connection to docker.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had company software installed that was messing with my ssl-certificates